# PowerApps: Compound IF statement?

Tags: powerapp, conditional

On my screen I have two fields called ***InspectionDueFreq*** and ***InspectionDueProb***.

The former represents the frequency of inspections (in days). If, for example, a part is to be inspected every 30 days and it has been 31 days since the last inspection, then the field text is set  to YES.

The latter represents a manual setting in a SP Online custom list. If a supplier has quality issues with their products, they are put on Probation by our quality lab and every shipment is inspected.

I have a label field which will serve as a visual flag. I want (I think) an IF statement that says: **if either field is Yes**, then set the flag text to "INSPECTION DUE NOW", otherwise set it to "No Inspection Needed". This will have conditional formatting in the Color parameter as well.

[image]

I've played with several attempts and searched for an example like this, but I'm not having any luck. Here is my current attempt:

```
If((InspectionDueFreq.Text Or InspectionDueProb.Text="YES"),"INSPECTION DUE NOW","No Inspection Needed")
```

The error I'm getting is "*Invalid number of arguments: received 1, expecting 2 or more*"

Am I on the right track using a compound IF formula, or should I be using a Switch formula?

Thanks,
gpence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I discovered the paren issue. It should read:

```
If(((InspectionDueFreq.Text="YES") Or (InspectionDueProb.Text="YES")),"INSPECTION DUE NOW","No Inspection Needed")
```

gpence